# If height greater than /w Bootstrap collapsed nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a few issues with setting the height of a div once the page has been resized and the button has been pressed for the navigation.

From the code bellow I believe should work. It does not even show a alert when the navbar is re-sized and button clicked.

```
if ($('.nav-collapse').height() > 2) {
    alert("hello");
    $(".navBarJquery").css({
        "top": pos.top,
        "height": hei
    });
}
```

[Link to Live demo](http://isca01.bigwavemedia.info/~watfordy/)

Comment: `$('.nav-collapse').height()` equals 0 when I put breakpoint. that's not larger than 2 thus no alert. The mentioned part of code is not inside the resize handler and will not be executed upon a resize.

Comment: But i was to action this to action when you click the button and the height is over 2. Basically when you click the button the height of the nav-collapse changes.

Comment: The code you mention is inside the `$(document).ready()` which is only executed after the page has loaded. Since you do not have this `alert` in the `$(window).resize(...)` it will not be executed when the window resizes, nor on any other event. From your explanation it is not clear what you actually want the code to do.

Comment: All i need it to do is alert when the height of .nav-collapse is over 2. I have tried putting this in the re-size and this has not worked. Thanks

Comment: I don't see this `.nav-collapse` having any other height than 0. If I give it a height (e.g. 20px) it will trigger the alert now that you have put the code into the resize. So, you need to find out why your `nav-collapse` height is 0

Comment: Iv tried using the above which does not work for some reason, but iv tried the .on function and it kind-of works...until you you close the button.

Comment: worked out a pure css solution.

Comment: Ok. Please add your solution as answer, and mark it as answer when you can. This will benefit the community

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added a background-color to .navbar-inner instead of trying to track it with jquery and add a background in with it.